# How do you check if an embedded document exists in a document in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

How do you check if an embedded document exists for a document using mongoid in Ruby on Rails?  Say I have a document `user` that has `name`, `email`, and might have a `nicknames` embedded document.  Right now if I run `user.first.nicknames` and if that `user` doesn't have the `nicknames` embedded document in it, it will error out. I've tried `matches?` and `exists?` but they don't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should return true if it doesn't exist `User.first.nicknames.nil?` and this will return true if it does exist: `User.first.nicknames.present?`

Comment: These both do not work on a mongoDB document that does not have `nicknames`.  It produces a "NoMethodError: undefined method `nicknames`" error.  This does work for documents that do have `nicknames`..

Comment: That is not what mine does, I'm using MongoId 2.3.3. It seems to me that the `User.first` is actually nil. So you are trying to call `nicknames` on a nil object. Can you verify that?

Answer (score 14):

With a little help from the other answers here, I found something that worked for me and I think this is what the original poster had in mind;

```
Model.where(:"subdoc.some_attribute".exists => true)
```

This will return all documents where the "some_attribute" exists on the subdocument.
Notice the syntax of the symbol, that's what I was missing.

Comment: You can also go through the association: `Model.subdocs.where(:field.exists => true)`.

Comment: This is what I was searching for all day long. It isn't documented anywhere!?

Answer (score 2):

You can do `User.where(:nicknames.exists => true).include?(user)`.

`User.where(:nicknames.exists => true)` will return only the documents which contain `nicknames`.

Answer (score 0):

should be as simple as `{"user":{"$exists":"nicknames"}}`

Comment: Is this a mongo shell command?  I am looking for a solution in Ruby on Rails.